# worklight apps not working on after installed device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am developed sample worklight http adapter. it working fine then i am going to tested for worklight simulator and android simulator it's both are working fine. while i move to install the in that app on android device i am getting error for url connection is failure and connection refuse problem . then i am going customized change the ipaddress and port number on android project for wlclient.properties then generate APK file it's working fine. this is right way to develop the application or otherwise any configuration level shall i do this? please any think let me shared information

Answer (score 0):

by default WL studio will inject one of the IPs available on your machine. If you're using WL 5.x you can change worklightServerRootUrl property in application-descriptor.xml
If your on WL 6.x right-click your app and select run->build for remote server